# How to change BgImage dynamically using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking for a way to dynamically change the BgImage of an HTML document with JS. I know about hardcoding the links, but I want to load it from a variable url that I provide.
This is what's working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background image</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/B95LprK.jpg')";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But this is what I need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background image</button>

<script>
var imageLink = 'https://i.imgur.com/B95LprK.jpg'
function myFunction() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(imageLink)";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a template literal string with backticks `` ` ` `` in which you can inject variables.

```
var imageLink = 'https://i.imgur.com/B95LprK.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLink})`;
```

An older way of doing it is by concatenating strings with the `+` operator.

```
var imageLink = 'https://i.imgur.com/B95LprK.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageLink + ")";
```

Comment: Hey, but when I give the value at runtime, via a prompt(), it doesnt work. Know why?

Comment: Seems like an unrelated issue. I don't know what you passed to the `prompt()` or what value you got back from it.